# While Testing with Espresso, how can I login into my app once and then execute all Test Suite ? Currently, app restarts for each test

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

In Android Studio, in the androidTest folder, I have a couple of test cases, like as follows :

[Screenshot : Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzBlz.png)
After each test class is executed, the app exits and is re-launched for next test. User have to login every time.

Is there any way I can login just once and execute all the test cases (entire test suite) without app exiting every-time ?

Answer (score 0):

You can 'mock' this step before each test method (@Before annotation in JUnit) or before the entire test class (@BeforeClass annotation in JUnit) but it requires external dependency for example Mockito.

Comment: Thankyou @Daniel for your suggestion.
Though I solved this problem and a couple of more (flakiness, shared state handling) using Google's Orchestrator
link is here for anybody's reference : https://www.polidea.com/blog/Keep-Espresso-Tests-Stable-with-Android-Test-Orchestrator/